# Python function sharing across import

Tags: python, import

I have a file structure like this:

```
MyProgram
  run.py
  log.py
  texts.py

# run.py
   import texts
   import log

# texts.py
   error_msg = "this is an error message"
   warning_msg = "this is a warning message"

# log.py
   print(error_msg)
```

is it possible somehow to access to a variable which is located in another file without additional imports?

So I don't want to import `texts.py` into `log.py`, the only connection between theese two files is `run.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im afraid that wouldnt be possible.
Why are multiple imports so bad? In Python it doestn matter if you import a module one or 20 times, python itself when loading a module allways checks in sys.modules first where if you imported it before it will be found. So to conclude, besides wasting space multiple import of the same module dont affect your code at all.

For more detailed info you should be able to finde soemthing here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

To have all imports in one import create a Python Package and then import the python package. A Python package itself is not much more than a Folder in which you have your modules and a `__init__.py` file in which you write which modules the Package should allow access too.

Example of your Folder structure:

```
->Classes
   -> log
   -> texts
   -> __init__.py
```

Comment: because I'am making automated tests, _test1, test2, test3_ theese sharing the same things (for eg.: log function, texts etc...). and i'am thinking about to make a _run_ file and this will run them after each other, but the imports will be 3as much as probably needed?!

Comment: It doestn matter if you import a module one or 20 times, python itself when loading a module allways checks in sys.modules first where if you imported it before it will be found. So to conclude, besides wasting space multiple import of the same module dont affect your code at all.

Comment: Thats okay, thank you for answering. 
One another thing, if i have more than 100tests, it is not so easy to maintain them. if one addinional import comes to all of the cases

Comment: You can create a python package out of your imports by creating a Folder in which you put the Modules you want to import and add a __init__.py File, in which you then write your imports. All you have to do then is import the FOlder in which you have your __init__.py and your modules. If a module is added all you have to do is add it to the folder and the import to the __init__.py and done.

Answer (score 0):

In your case u don't really need log.py file. Just import texts.py to run.py and print what u want

```
from texts import *

print(error_msg)
```

But if u want to have all three files you have to use oop

## run.py

```
from texts import *
from log import *

ermsg(error_msg)
```

## log.py

```
def ermsg(msg):
    print(msg)
```

## texts.py

```
error_msg = "this is an error message"
warning_msg = "this is a warning message"
```

Comment: Yes i know, this just was an example. But in my case this is not a way how i can solve it

Comment: So tell us, we may help :)